# Sites API doesn't have good way to return all sites

Tags: feature-request, support, api

## EDIT

To sum up the comment discussions, this has turned into a feature request for the `/sites` API to have an ALL parameter (like `0`?) to the pagesize argument.

## Original Post

Why aren't all Stack Exchange site available in the API?

Off the top of my head there is the [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site, the [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) site, [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) and many more.

Why is this?

Any release date for the other sites?

Edit: Here are the sites I have `serverfault,superuser,meta,webapps,meta.webapps,gaming,meta.gaming,webmasters,meta.webmasters,cooking,meta.cooking,gamedev,meta.gamedev,photo,meta.photo,stats,meta.stats,math,meta.math,diy,meta.diy,meta.superuser,meta.serverfault,gis,meta.gis,tex,meta.tex,askubuntu,meta.askubuntu`.

A bug in [StacMan](https://github.com/emmettnicholas/StacMan)? I am simply using `StacManClient.Sites.GetAll()` that is documented as `Get all the sites in the Stack Exchange network. (API Method: "/sites")`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? All those sites should be available through the API.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I am using the StacMan library for .NET. It just requests from the API. I edited my question with the list of sites I get.

Comment: I assume the paging functionality is generic so if implemented this will become possible on all API calls. I don't have high hopes this will be implemented given the possibility of hogging resources on the server when such requests fetch all data and stream back all results to the caller.

Comment: @rene: I still think that this is something that should be implemented for sites, but this should Only be for sites.

Comment: You should make clear in your feature request that you only want this for the /sites endpoint

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The API returns results [in pages](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging), defaulting to 30 items per page. Since there's far more sites on the network, you need to request subsequent pages, or use a larger page size. The maximum page size for API requests is usually 100 items, but in the case of the `/sites` route it's unbounded.

StacMan allows you to pass in a `pagesize` parameter to the `GetAll()` method, so if you want to avoid paging you can pass in something appropriately big. See [this similar Stack Apps question](https://stackapps.com/questions/4785/stackexchange-api-sites-does-not-return-all-the-sites) for more.

Comment: Perhaps I should change the question to why doesn't the API allow an ALL parameter for pagesize.

Comment: It would be marginally more convenient, but using a big number/iterating over the pages by checking the response for `has_more` works well enough that I guess it hasn't been a priority.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN You can also visit API [Usage of /sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) page and run the query with options. Tim Stone is correct about pagesize. Here is a sample query I made with [pagesize 300](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=300&filter=!mr7eSsT3b6)  which returns all sites.

Comment: @HackerKarma: I put 9999999 for good measure. Maybe SO will grow larger than 300 sites......     :D

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN Yes, SE/SO will have that many sites in future.. I will be long gone though :D I may see 300 but not 9999999 :)

Comment: @HackerKarma: Still, its a nuisance.

Answer (score 2):

> To sum up the comment discussions, this has turned into a feature request for the /sites API to have an ALL parameter (like 0?) to the pagesize argument.

But, it already has that. From the `/sites` [documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites):

> The `pagesize` parameter for this method is unbounded, in acknowledgement that for many applications repeatedly fetching from `/sites` would complicate start-up tasks needlessly.

This means you can do something like:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=1000&filter=default&run=true
```

And return all sites (assuming that SE stays under 1000 total sites).